# Ubuntu Mate desktop's theme is not changing in accordance with the rest

Tags: themes, ubuntu-mate

After a recent update for some reason my desktop theme is not changing to numix-circle theme.

I think it is the software update problem because it was fine before the update and I haven't really changed anything else.

Here is how it looks compared to the rest of the theme:

[image]

Comment: Go into the "Startup applications" utility (in the system > preferences menu), and make sure that "Mate settings daemon" is enabled. Is it ?